# Orchard collaboration

Tags: orchardcms

Recently I'm making a web page using orchard, and I'm trying to create a Q&A page by using orchard collaboration. I know by using ticket-dashboard I can easily come up with a result like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d00js.png).The questions will be divided into different groups according to the project it is about. But right now I am thinking of letting the administrator to see each project's [project-dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0SGo.png) when clicking on ticket-dashboard. Can anybody let me know about how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some options that can help you. One of them that comes to my mind is this.

1. Customizing ProjectDriver for a new DisplayType like "ProjectTicketDashboard". If you take a look at the ProjectDriver.Display method, it renders ProjectDetail (which contains portlets) for the Detail display type. You can add a new "case statement" there for the new DisplayType. For the new display Type, you can represents a ticket dashboard. Something like this:

   ```
               case "ProjectTicketDashboard":
               // Query the counts of the whole tickets in the system based on stateId
               dynamic state = new JObject();

               var contentQuery = this.services.ContentManager.HqlQuery().ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published);

               state.ContentTypes = "Ticket";
               contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "Content", "ContentTypes", state);

               state.Project_Id = part.Id;
               contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "AttachToProjectFilter", "Id", state);

               var ticketCountsByStateIds = groupQuery.GetCount(contentQuery, "TicketPartRecord", "StatusRecord.Id");

               model.AllTickets = new Collection<dynamic>();
               CRMHelper.AddStatusGroupRecordsToModel(statusRecords, ticketCountsByStateIds, model.AllTickets);

               state.MaxDueDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
               contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, TicketFieldsFilter.CategoryName, TicketFieldsFilter.TicketDueDateType, state);
               model.AllOverrudeItemsCount = contentQuery.Count();

               return ContentShape("Parts_Project_Dashboard",
                      () => shapeHelper.Parts_Project_Dashboard(
                            Model: model
                         ));
   ```

   2. You need a corresponding view for the Parts_Project_Dashboard and the associated entry in the placement.info. For the view, you can reuse the code of the view in Orchard.CRM.Core/Views/Parts/Dashboard.cshtml
   3. Next step, you can create a custom Query that gets all projects with a shape layout and DisplayType = "ProjectTicketDashboard".
   4. And finally, use a projection to display the previous query in the HomePage

Let me know, if you have any further questions.
Siyamand

Comment: I will try it! Thank you for your help~

Comment: Hi Siyamand, I have another question to ask you. Right now when I use the administrator account to see ticket dashboard I will see two ticket summaries one is "Your tickets summary" and the other "All tickets summary", is it able to add more summary on the dashboard?

Comment: Hi Austin, there are several approaches to do so. [Orchard Collaboration](http://orchardcollaboration.com) uses a widget to represents Ticket Summaries (both for the user and for the admin). The main logic is in the DashboardDriver at Modules/Orchard.CRM.Core/Drivers. You need to create a new Widget similar to that one. DashboardDriver represents tickets of the logined user as well as summary of all tickets. In the new widget, you can only represents summary tickets of the user. The new widget must have a UserId property and represents ticket summary of that user instead of the logined user.